CPLEX Error: Data element "Products" has already been set
I'm working on a CPLEX model using .mod and .dat files and encountering this error.
It seems that Products is defined more than once. Here's the current situation:
In the .mod file, I have {string} Products;.
In the .dat file, I assign values with Products = {"Spaetzle", "Pasta"};.
If I remove Products from the .mod file, I get another error saying that Products does not exist.
What’s the correct way to resolve this? Should I define Products only in .dat, or is there a better way to handle this?
.mod file:
/*********************************************
 * OPL 22.1.1.0 Model
 * Author: berka
 * Creation Date: Nov 22, 2024 at 12:43:38 AM
 *********************************************/

 /* EXPRESSIONS OF DECISION VARIABLES:
 
 dexpr (Derived Expression), OPL'de bir matematiksel ifadeyi temsil etmek için kullanılan bir anahtar sözcüktür.
 Bir kez tanımlandıktan sonra, o ifade bir değişken adı gibi kullanılabilir.
 
 Ör:
 
 dexpr float Objective = sum(i in I) c[i] * x[i]; // Türetilmiş bir amaç fonksiyonu ifadesi
minimize Objective;                              // Bu ifadeyi minimize et

Burada Objective, tüm c[i] * x[i] çarpımlarının toplamını temsil eden bir expression (ifade) haline gelir.

ASSERTIONS:

assert bir kontrol mekanizmasıdır ve modelin belirli bir koşulu sağlamasını zorunlu kılar.
Eğer assert koşulu sağlanmazsa, model bir hata verir ve çalışmayı durdurur.
Bu, genellikle veri tutarlılığını veya mantıksal gereklilikleri doğrulamak için kullanılır.

Ör:

range J = 1..6;                           // 1'den 6'ya kadar olan tamsayıları içeren "J" aralığını tanımlar.
range I = 1..3;                           // 1'den 3'e kadar olan tamsayıları içeren "I" aralığını tanımlar.

float a[J] = ...;                         // "J" aralığındaki elemanlar için tanımlanmış bir float dizisi. Değerler daha sonra atanacak.
float b[I] = ...;                         // "I" aralığındaki elemanlar için tanımlanmış bir float dizisi. Değerler daha sonra atanacak.

assert sum(j in J) a[j] >= sum(i in I) b[i];
                                           // Assert ifadesi: "J" aralığındaki a[j]'lerin toplamı, "I" aralığındaki b[i]'lerin toplamına eşit veya daha büyük olmalıdır.
 
 
 */
 
 // PPP with Assertions Example
 
 // Sets
{string} Products;                     // Ürünleri tanımlayan küme (örneğin: Spaetzle, Pasta).
{string} Resources;                    // Kaynakları tanımlayan küme (örneğin: Flour, Eggs).

// Parameters
float Stock[Resources];                // Kaynakların stok miktarlarını tutan parametre (örneğin: Flour = 130, Eggs = 100).
float Demand[Products];                // Ürünlerin talep miktarlarını tutan parametre (örneğin: Spaetzle = 100, Pasta = 150).
float Consumption[Products][Resources];// Ürünlerin kaynak tüketim oranlarını tanımlayan iki boyutlu parametre matrisi.
float Income[Products];                // Ürünlerin gelirlerini tutan parametre (örneğin: Spaetzle = 1.5, Pasta = 2).

// Decision variables
dvar float+ Quantity[Products];        // Ürünlerin üretim miktarlarını temsil eden pozitif karar değişkenleri.
 
 
 // Expression of decision variables
dexpr float Profit = sum(p in Products) Income[p] * Quantity[p]; 
                                                // Amaç fonksiyonunu tanımlayan türetilmiş ifade (derived expression).
                                                // Ürünlerin gelirleriyle üretim miktarlarının çarpımının toplamı kârı (Profit) temsil eder.

// Assertion
assert sum(p in Products) Demand[p] <= 100;    // Talebin toplamının 100'den büyük olmadığını kontrol eden doğrulama ifadesi.
                                               // Eğer koşul sağlanmazsa model hata verir ve çalışmayı durdurur.

// Objective function
maximize Profit;                               // Amaç: Profit ifadesini maksimize etmek.

// Constraints
subject to {
  forall(r in Resources)                      // Kaynakların her biri için kısıt tanımlar.
    sum(p in Products) Consumption[p][r] * Quantity[p] <= Stock[r];
                                               // Her kaynağın tüketimi, mevcut stoğunu aşamaz.

  forall(p in Products)                       // Her ürün için kısıt tanımlar.
    Quantity[p] <= Demand[p];                 // Her ürünün üretim miktarı, talep miktarını aşamaz.
}
 

.dat file:
/*********************************************
 * OPL 22.1.1.0 Data
 * Author: berka
 * Creation Date: Nov 22, 2024 at 12:49:09 AM
 *********************************************/

// Parameters
Products = {"Spaetzle", "Pasta"};        // Ürünleri tanımlayan küme. Örneğin, Spaetzle ve Pasta.
Resources = {"Flour", "Eggs"};          // Kaynakları tanımlayan küme. Örneğin, Flour ve Eggs.

Stock = [130, 100];                     // Her kaynak için mevcut stok miktarları: Flour = 130, Eggs = 100.
Consumption = [[3, 1], [2, 2]];         // Ürünlerin kaynak tüketim oranları:
                                        // Spaetzle: 3 Flour, 1 Egg.
                                        // Pasta: 2 Flour, 2 Eggs.
Demand = [100, 150];                    // Her ürün için talep miktarları: Spaetzle = 100, Pasta = 150.
Income = [1.5, 2];                      // Her ürünün gelirleri: Spaetzle = 1.5, Pasta = 2.


They are in the same Run Configuration. I couldn't find a solution. Please help.

how is it related to C? Using unrelated top rated tags is considering spam

Since Products is defined in the .dat
You should turn
{string} Products; 

from the .mod to
{string} Products=...;

Of course the same applies to
{string} Products=...;                     // Ürünleri tanımlayan küme (örneğin: Spaetzle, Pasta).
{string} Resources=...;                    // Kaynakları tanımlayan küme (örneğin: Flour, Eggs).

// Parameters
float Stock[Resources]=...;                // Kaynakların stok miktarlarını tutan parametre (örneğin: Flour = 130, Eggs = 100).
float Demand[Products]=...;                // Ürünlerin talep miktarlarını tutan parametre (örneğin: Spaetzle = 100, Pasta = 150).
float Consumption[Products][Resources]=...;// Ürünlerin kaynak tüketim oranlarını tanımlayan iki boyutlu parametre matrisi.
float Income[Products]=...;                // Ürünlerin gelirlerini tutan parametre (örneğin: Spaetzle = 1.5, Pasta = 2).

